# Spark temporary view not found

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which I created from a hive table

```
df =  spark.sql("""select * from table """)
```

I want to create a temporary table from the dataframe so that I can run spark sql queries on it
I have tried both of the following methods

```
df.registerTempTable('test_table1')
df.createTempView('test_table1')
```

But whenever I try to run the following I get table not found

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from test_table limit 100").show()
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Table or view not found: test_table; line 1 pos 21'
```

Note: My spark version is 2.3

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here ?

Comment: `test_table_ot` is not the temporary view name you registered?

Comment: thats a typo. test_table is the one I created

Answer (score 2):

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 14, 'A'),
    (1, 15, 'c'),
    (2, 16, 'A'),
], ["column1", "column2", 'column3'])

temp.createOrReplaceTempView('test_table1')

print(spark.version)
# 2.3.2.0101-hw-2.1.0.dli-SNAPSHOT

sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from test_table1 limit 100").show()
# +--------+
# |count(1)|
# +--------+
# |       3|
# +--------+
spark.sql("select count(*) from test_table1 limit 100").show()
# +--------+
# |count(1)|
# +--------+
# |       3|
# +--------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the dataframe I wanted using spark.sql. Do you know why spark.sql can find the temporary view but the sqlContext can not ?

Comment: i can find the temp view using `sqlContext.sql` either.